# Is there a alternative to insert each Modelpart individually in a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, viewmodel

I asked myself if there is a alternative to insert each modelpart of a model to declare a content from my modelview to my model individually.

For example I have a model class:

```
public partial class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Serial { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

and my **ViewModel** looks like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
     public List<Data.Models.Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Now in my **controller** I don't want to do this:

```
//...
Product newProducts = new Product
{
    ProductName= ViewModel.Product.ProductName,
    //and so on
}
//...
```

With this I mean to add every part of the model individually... it's quite time consuming if you have a large database table. It should also be possible to use this shortcut if the database tables aren't quite similar. For example if the ViewModel has an additional column.

I hope you will understand my problem and I am looking forward to your answers.

Comment: Can't you simply use newProducts = ViewModel.Product ? considering both side are Product type.

Comment: i thought of that, but sometimes i have quite similar databasetables which arnt the same, so with them i cant do that.

Comment: If both types are not compatible then you can't type cast directly. You have to map every field.

Comment: and there isnt a way visual studio can help me. e.g. adds all fields at once so i just have to do the other half part of declaring?